# Sorting array of strings causes seg fault

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to write a sort to sort an array of strings in ascending order I have the function as:

```
void mySort(string list[], int size) { 
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
        for (int j=0; j < size-i; j++){
            if (strcmp(list[j].c_str(),list[j+1].c_str())< 0);{
                std::swap(list[j], list[j + 1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then the function that uses the sort:

```
void q0run(question q){

std::string input = q.programInput;                             //Place the data file in a variable
//cout << input << endl;                                        //Test to make sure data file stored correctly - works
std::ifstream inputFile (input.c_str());                        //Open File
    if(inputFile.good()){                                       //Make sure file is open before trying to work with it
                                                                //Begin Working with information
        cout << "In File:  \t" << input << endl;
        int number_of_lines = 0;
        std::string line;
        while (std::getline(inputFile, line)){
            ++number_of_lines;
        }
        std::cout << "Number of lines in text file: " << number_of_lines << endl;
        std::string dataStorage[number_of_lines];
        inputFile.clear();
        inputFile.seekg(0);
        for(int loop=0;loop<number_of_lines;loop++){
            getline(inputFile,dataStorage[loop]);
        }
        mySort(dataStorage,number_of_lines);
        for(int loop=0;loop<number_of_lines;loop++){
            cout << dataStorage[loop] << endl;
        }
        inputFile.close();
    }else{
        cout << "Could not open file!!!" << endl;
    }

 }
```

When I run the program though it segfaults at the sort. Not sure what I'm doing wrong:

```
      In File:        data01a.txt
      Number of lines in text file: 253
      Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The array to be sorted is being populated, I can run a loop on it and print it all out unsorted, any ideas? An easier sorting method will be fine too! Thanks!

Comment: In the first iteration, `i` will be `0`, `j` will go up to `size-0`, and then you access `j+1`, which will be out of bounds.

Comment: Anything wrong with `std::sort(list, list+size);`?

Comment: and there's an extra `;` so the swap is unconditional

Comment: @Manu343726: `operator==` is not equivalent to `strcmp`. You mean `std::string::compare`.

Comment: strcmp is NOT deprecated unless you are using a Microsoft compiler telling you that parts of the standard library are unsafe.

operator== won't work here as is trying to compare for <

Comment: Lightness Races in Orbit, std::string::compare actually calls char_traits<char>::compare which uses memcmp anyway.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit thanks, was a typo :)

Comment: @CashCow: And? So? Therefore? The OP doesn't need to create two C-style strings in a nested loop just to call `strcmp`. `std::string::compare` may do this logic on its internal buffers. That it eventually invokes `memcmp` itself is not relevant at all.

Comment: Yes, I know. I just wonder why you'd use compare at all when you can use operator<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (strcmp(list[j].c_str(),list[j+1].c_str())< 0);{
```

Oops!

- There's an extra `;` so the swap will always occur;
- Your inner loop needs one fewer iterations, otherwise `j+1` jumps off the end;
- And are all those C-string conversions really necessary?
  `std::string::compare` would do the job...

Comment: I'll give you the green check when it lets me.

Comment: shoot, still segfaults

Comment: It would, but that only calls memcmp down the line via char_traits<char>.

Answer (score 0):

The actual bug in your code was answered in a comment.

Your "j+1" index can be out of bounds and in the first iteration it is. You therefore need to loop j up to size-i-1 or iterate i from 1 onward, thus..

```
for (int i=1; i<size; i++)
```

I assume this is some kind of exercise as the correct way to sort is simply to use `std::sort`.

You have also been offered alternative ways to compare two strings, the simplest of which is just its overloaded operator<, thus

```
if( list[j] < list[j+1] )
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an out of bounds access which may be the cause

```
for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
        for (int j=0; j < size-i; j++){
            if (strcmp(list[j].c_str(),list[j+1].c_str())< 0){
                std::swap(list[j], list[j + 1]);
            }
```

On the first iteration you have

```
i=0; j=size-1 =>strcmp(list[size-1].c_str(),list[size])
```

change the stop condition in the first loop:

```
 for (int i=0; i<size-1; i++){
            for (int j=0; j < size-i; j++){
                if (strcmp(list[j].c_str(),list[j+1].c_str())< 0){
                    std::swap(list[j], list[j + 1]);
                }
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This code does what you want in C++11:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string s1 = "hello";
    string s2 = "world!";
    string s3 = "peanut";
    string s4 = "butter";

    array<string,4> ar = {s1,s2,s3,s4};
    sort(ar.begin(),ar.end());

    for(auto elem : ar)
        cout << elem << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have news for you. sort has a default 3rd parameter that uses std::less<string>() and believe it or not, that actually already implements what you want so no need for your lambda.

Comment: Yeah it is a common feature of human nature that when you get a new tool you want to rush and use it even when not appropriate. I love lambdas too :)